# Cannot see the graphical display of the virtual device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

so I am working on an Android app. Now I am trying to go into res-menu-layout-activity_main to design the virtual device. But when I open it, id does not give me the display of the virtual device. Any thoughts what needs to be done? Below is a screenshot of it.

[image]

Here is the XML file of it. It looks a little messy and confusing. Besically, I just want all four fields be left-aligned, listed as viewLats, view4, viewLongs, view1.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.oldimagereveal.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLongs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLongs"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textLongs"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textLats"
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've had some weird issues similar to this in the pat. Completely removing eclipse and reinstalling seemed to be the only solution

Comment: the reason is clearly stated in the error message: you cannot use circular dependencies inside a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @ghostbust555 please take a look at the error message before suggesting something like that

Comment: I was trying to fix the layout in XML but since I do not have a visual display of the screen, it is a little confusing. Can I just undo all settings of graphic layout somehow.

Comment: @Droidman Fair enough. couldn't see it initially until I zoomed in

Answer (score 0):

Since I had no idea how to fix this problem. I went to the Layout XML file and deleted all Textview fields I set up earlier. Now it's giving the original screen and I can go back and set it up again.